# How can I update a property showing text length when my class is updated?

Tags: c#

I have the following class. Note there are some key values which are not shown:

```
namespace Storage.Models
{
    public abstract class AuditableTable 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I would like to store the length of the Text property in a variable called TextLength. Is it possible for me to do this automatically when an instance of the class is created or when the class is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a property, unless you want to record the initial value:

```
    public int TextLength
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

However, if you do want to record the initial length, you can do:

```
    string m_Text;

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Text;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Text = value;
            if (m_TextLength == 0)
            {
                m_TextLength = value.Length;
            }
        }
    }

    private int m_TextLength;

    public int TextLength
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TextLength;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a property with a getter:

```
public abstract class AuditableTable 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int TextLength
    {
        get { return this.Text.Length; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to run reports that include the length column. Do you think it would be okay to do this way or should I set up the value when I store the data?

Comment: It would probably be OK to do it this way unless your reporting engine has some bizarre quirks.